# Modify behaviour of "s" parameter in wp_query

Tags: query, search

I'm having an issue with the "s" parameter in wp_query.

When someone search a text with two or more words, wp_query split the criteria in two or more parameters. For example :

```
[no_found_rows] => 
            [search_terms_count] => 3
            [search_terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => online
                    [1] => books
                )

        [search_orderby_title] => Array
            (
                [0] => wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%online%'
                [1] => wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%books%'
            )
```

How can I modify that behaviour in wp_query, so if I search "Online books" just use the whole text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works the same way Google etc work, to search for an exact phrase, wrap it in quotes

e.g. `online books` vs `"online books"`